# Match a selected set of keys in one hash to those keys in an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby, hash

I am looking to match a selected set of keys in one hash to those keys in an array of hashes.

The following does not work as the hashes `new_q` and `old_q` (`oq`) can't accept four keys. They will all be strings, so I could join them together and look for the match (but `join` is not a hash method).

Does anyone have ideas how to make this concise, without a bunch of `&&`s?  I tried to make an array as well, which seems like it should work, but I can't find the syntax.

```
if old_q.select { |oq| oq["cn", "dt", "ti", "in"] == new_q["cn", "dt", "ti", "in"] }.length > 0


if old_q.select { |oq| [oq["cn"], oq["dt"], oq["ti"], oq["in"]] == [new_q["cn"], new_q["dt"], new_q["ti"], new_q["in"]] }.length > 0
```

Comment: Why are you using select? Is `old_q` a hash or an array of hashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) is what you're looking for:

```
oq.values_at("cn", "dt", "ti", "in")
```

Comment: I guess that is why it is best to look at the most current documentations.  values_at is not in my book.  Thanks!